# Can the Euclidean algorithm fail by not terminating in non Euclidean domains?

Tags: algorithms, ring-theory, factoring

Is it possible for the Euclidean algorithm to fail by not terminating in finite time in non-Euclidean domains? In $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ it can fail by going out of the ring, ie one gets a non integer element.

I asked my prof, and he told me his intuition told him they should but he couldn't think up an example on the spot. Does anybody know of an explicit example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Euclidean domain $R$ you require the existence of a function $f : R \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \Bbb{N}$ such that for $a, b \in R$, $b \ne 0$, there exist $q, r \in R$ such that $a = b q + r$, and either $r = 0$, or $f(r) < f(b)$.

> So what are the rules of your game here? You allow the function $f$ to take values in a linearly ordered set in which there are infinite, strictly descending sequences?

If this is the case, then one could construct a fairly pathological example by taking $R = \Bbb{Q}[x]$, and letting $f = \deg$ take values in $\Bbb{N}$ with the *reverse* ordering (except for zero, perhaps), that is, division takes the form
$$
a = b q + r,\qquad
\text{with $\deg(r) > \deg(b)$}.
$$
So when you divide the degree of the remainder *increases* each time, and there's no chance of stopping. For instance with $a = x$, $b = x^2$, a legal division would be
$$
x = x^2 \cdot x + (x - x^3),
$$
where $q = x$ and $r = x - x^3$.